# how to get a persist storage path in an ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to store an image file to a persistent storage path in an ios app. I hope that I could also upload the image file to my server using this persistent storage path after the app restarted. I wrote the below code, but this can't work well for me. Could anyone help me?

```
- (NSString*)persistFilePath:(NSString*)extension
{
    NSString* docsPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory()stringByStandardizingPath];
    NSFileManager* fileMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; // recommended by Apple (vs [NSFileManager defaultManager]) to be threadsafe
    NSString* filePath;

    // unique file name
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
    do {
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%ld.%@", docsPath, @"cdv_photo", [timeStampObj longValue], extension];
    } while ([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    return filePath;
}
```

I tried the below code, but it doesn't work well too.

```
- (NSString*)persistFilePath:(NSString*)extension
{
    NSString* docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
    NSFileManager* fileMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; // recommended by Apple (vs [NSFileManager defaultManager]) to be threadsafe
    NSString* filePath;

    // unique file name
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];
    do {
        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%ld.%@", docsPath, @"cdv_photo", [timeStampObj longValue], extension];
    } while ([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);

    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: What does not work? The first way is pointless anyway because – as the name implies – a *temporary* directory is certainly not the right place for persistent data. And the `while` loops make no sense either because nothing is changing in their body. Apart from this you get **always** a unique value with `timeIntervalSince1970` relative to the current date.

Comment: Why don't you use NSFileManager APIs to get the list of existing files? For example,  `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`. But it's tough to offer good advice since you don't show how you saved the file. That makes it difficult to help with the code to load the file.